# child QMainWindow title bar disappeared on Mac OS X (add more description)

Tags: macos, qt4, titlebar, qmainwindow, qt4.8

I develop a program on mac OS X using Qt 4.8 as the title.
Now I'm facing a problem that I spent a lot of time on it but still cannot solve.

I have a QWidget (called A) which will open a QMainWindow (called B) after some operation.
When B is opened, I need A to be blocked by B, so I set A as B's parent and set the window modality of B to Qt::WindowModal.

On other platform, it works as what I thought, however, when it comes to mac, B doesn't have its own title bar, it just popped up and attached to the title bar of A. And also, the close button on the title bar of A is grey-out, which means I cannot close B by the button, I need to use an exit QAction on QMenu to close it.

When I set B's parent to 0(NULL) instead of B, then it has independent title bar just as on windows or linux, that's what I want. However it lost the property that B blocked by A.

I tried to set the windows flags such as Qt::CustomizeWindowHint and so on, but no one works.

Is there any way to keep the hierarchal relationship between A and B, and gives B an independent title bar on Mac? Thanks for everyone's help :)

ps. I tried on small program and found that this situation only happened on WindowModal (NonModal and ApplicationModal works fine)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are describing is known as *sheets* on Mac OS X.  As you suspected, there is a value for the window flags enum that specifies if the window is to be a sheet.  Based on [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowType-enum), it appears that calling [`setWindowModality()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowModality-prop) on OS X may default the window to being a sheet -- which is probably what most developers would want for most dialogs.  You might try testing for and explicitly removing that flag after setting the modality and see if that helps.  Alternately, you may want to check which flags are set, and see if that leads to a solution.

Comment: Thanks Caleb!
I generated the QMainWindow and set it to WindowModal by Qt Creator, it does call the setWindowModality function in generated ui_mainwindow file.
At first I didn't set any flag, then I tried Qt::Window, but the situation is same. The ui file didn't set any flag by default either.
As the description I added, this only happen under windowModal. NonModal and ApplicationModal isfine. Is it related?
All I can find on google is window flags, which I already did. I read the document, Qt::Window doesn't include sheet property.
Why it still behave as a sheet instead of a normal window?